# Grouping valuable with barplot in R studio

Tags: r, data-visualization

```
Income1.csv
  Age.Group     X   X.1   X.2   X.3  X.4
1    Income 16-24 25-34 35-44 45-54  55+
2       Low  13.9  17.4  14.9  11.9 10.9
3    Medium  26.3  46.9  42.2  30.7 21.5
4      High  11.6  19.7  22.4  17.4  6.7
```

How do you create a grouped barplot with the height as `Age`?  The picture below is what I want to create.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in some particular software? Which? Are you asking something else? What? (Be aware that 'how to do ___ in ___' questions are off topic here.)

Answer (score 0):

Read your data:

```
d <- dput(d)
structure(list(Income = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("High", 
"Low", "Medium"), class = "factor"), `16-24` = c(13.9, 26.3, 
11.6), `25-34` = c(17.4, 46.9, 19.7), `35-44` = c(14.9, 42.2, 
22.4), `45-54` = c(11.9, 30.7, 17.4), `55+` = c(10.9, 21.5, 6.7
)), .Names = c("Income", "16-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", 
"55+"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Plot your data: `beside` specifies that the values are plotted beside not stacked.

```
barplot(as.matrix(d[,-1]), beside = T, legend.text = d$Income)
```